# Collision via Character Controller doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collider

I use this code to detect collision on sides but it doesn't work. I have Character Controller attached to my player and box colliders on the blue boxes but it doesn't detect collision when i collide with them. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUpOg.png

```
void OnControllerColliderHit (ControllerColliderHit hit){

    if (controller.collisionFlags == CollisionFlags.Sides) {

        Debug.Log (hit.gameObject.name);
        Debug.DrawRay (hit.point, hit.normal, Color.red, 2f);
    }
```

Comment: A good suggestion is to put the `Debug.Log (hit.gameObject.name);` outside the if statement and see if you get any log at-all.

Comment: I did and i don't get anything either.

Comment: This is interesting. Can you verify that your cubes have colliders and that their colliders have `IsTrigger` disable/unchecked? Also add Rigidbody to each Collider and see what happens....

Comment: They are not set as triggers and i tested with rigidbody on blue boxes and it doesn't work either. It seems weird, yesterday i tried the same code on another project and it worked perfectly.

Comment: How are you moving the character controller?

Comment: if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W))
this.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;

Comment: Check my answer. That's likely the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`OnControllerColliderHit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.OnControllerColliderHit.html)  will only be called while Move is being performed. That move must be initiated by the CharacterController's [`Move`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) function instead of modifying its `transform.position` property directly.

```
public float speed = 6.0F;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
public float gravity = 20.0F;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
CharacterController controller;

void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= speed;
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

    }
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime); //This is how you move
}

void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{

    if (controller.collisionFlags == CollisionFlags.Sides)
    {

        Debug.Log(hit.gameObject.name);
        Debug.DrawRay(hit.point, hit.normal, Color.red, 2f);
    }
}
```